# How does one determine console character width from ruby program?

Tags: ruby, unix, terminal

I want to print columnar output from a ruby program, but in order to take full advantage of the available screen space, I need to determine the character width of the terminal the program is running in. How does one do this?

Comment: the width of a character or the width of the terminal in character's. The first is like impossible, the second is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HighLine](http://github.com/JEG2/highline/blob/master/lib/highline/system_extensions.rb#L44) gem uses this function to find the dimensions of a terminal:

```
  # A Windows savvy method to fetch the console columns, and rows.
  def terminal_size
    stdout_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

    bufx, bufy, curx, cury, wattr, left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy =
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout_handle)
    return right - left + 1, bottom - top + 1
  end
```

This method should work also on Windows, if you use Linux (or something similar) only then you can use `stty size` to find the dimensions more easily using something like:

```
def terminal_size
  `stty size`.split.map { |x| x.to_i }.reverse
end
```